# Round Cube Mesh

Tags: mesh

Good evening I want to make a sandy tropical island. I am using Blender 2.79b. I found a tutorial on YouTube. The author is using Blender 2.75. He is using Mesh->Round Cube->Sphere to make the island. Blender 2.79b does not have this option. I am a very very newbie. Is there a way to get this item? He does not want to use a UVSphere because with the Subdivision Modifier it will not look nice.

Comment: You can access the `Round Cube` object type from an add-on: `Add Mesh: Extra Objects`. This add-on is generally available by default; you just need to open your `Add-ons` interface and `Enable` it.

Comment: To the default cube, add a _Subdivision Surface Modifier_ (to the desired number of iterations - I usually find 2 or 3 works fine for most things), then add a _Cast Modifier_ set to "sphere" (default) and increase the factor to 1. Apply both modifiers.

Comment: you can also create your cube, go in Edit mode, subdivide and in the Operator box, raise the Smoothness value up to 1

Answer (score 3):

The round cube in the add on is not completely correct. Nor is the usual method of making one by subdividing a cube.

The problem is the 3 spoked poles(N-poles) where the corners of the cube were. They create a pinching effect when rendered. the vertices of these poles (and the vertices surrounding them) need to be moved in towards the centre of the sphere very slightly.

Start with a cube and add a subdivision surface modifier of level 3.
Apply it immediately.

In edit mode, slect everything in point select mode.

Press Ctrl-Alt-S to use the "to sphere" operation.

Drag the mouse all the way the right to make the usual quad sphere.

Select just the vertices with 3 edges coming from them (there are 8)

Scale them down by 0.9946 (it's a small amount but makes a big difference!)

Expand the selection by pressing "ctrl-+".

Scale these vertices by 0.9983 (an even smaller amount!)

you can now add any subdivision surface modifier to it and it will look good. Level 3 is the usual.

You can see it here:

https://youtu.be/aRSVYFrRWeU

Comment: Hi and welcome! Interesting solution. Unfortunately, your answer is a "link only answer". There is no further information without watching the video. The problem is that readers in the future will have no idea what you talking about when the video is offline. Add the relevant information to your answer to improve its quality.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed.